# Change display before pausing

Tags: android

I have an app that will have sensitive information displayed on the screen and I would like it to finish() to get back to the log in screen when the user leaves the app, so that it will not be displaying that sensitive information in the running apps list.
I've tried calling finish() in the onPause() before the super.onPause(), but that only changes the display once you get back to the app.
I've tried setVisible(false) but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25107516/115145

Answer (score 0):

Thank you CommonsWare, that solved my problem.
Set the "secure" flag so that the window is blanked in the apps list:

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```