# How to change Android thumbnail to protect sensitive data

Tags: android, thumbnails

Our Android app may present sensitive data and we wish to hide it when the app is not in use - Android is taking a snapshot of the app and displays it in the [overview screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html). At the same time we want to enable the user to take screen shots of the app when using it. We already checked following options:

1. Using [FLAG_SECURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE) - Answers the need to hide the app in the overview screen but completely blocks the user from taking any screen shot of the app
2. Using onPause to change the activity content. Specifically we tried to show there the splash screen. We do see the splash screen appears when the app is minimizing, but the thumbnail presents the app before the splash appeared, meaning this is too late.

Any idea how we can hide/change the activity before the app moves to the background and still keep the print screen ability when the user is using the app?

Here are some links about the issue - all are only partial to this question:

- [How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)
- [Hide a view before onStop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107516/hide-a-view-before-onstop)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to set FLAG_SECURE in onPause() and take it out in onResume()?

Comment: Already tried that and it did not work :-(

Comment: How about implementing the snapshot function in the app? Then you could use the FLAG_SECURE and let the user take a screenshot by capturing the UI frame through code. But that of course will also have impact on usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is removing the app from recent apps completely an option? Then set `android:excludeFromRecent` to true for the activity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it will hurt the user experience, as the user is expecting the app to be there. Looking for a better solution (it is so simple in iOS and I am hoping to find some kind of a solution to android)

Comment: Strangely Android does not offer a proper way to handle this and eventually I chose using the [android:excludeFromRecent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) setting as @Kim suggested. Hopefully at some point Android will answer this basic issue.